# Possible to call function from Angular 4 component template property?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was wonder if its possible to call a function from the template property of an an Angular 4 component like below? I was hoping to either return the template as a string from a function or possibly even the template url. The template would be chosen based on the @Input string value and be part of the function signature.

Currently i am getting "this.getTemplate is not a function"

Any help would be appreciated!

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css'],
  template: this.getTemplate(this.templateName)
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

     @Input() templateName: string = '';

     getTemplate(name: string) : string {

        if (name == "first") {
            return `<h5>First Template</h5>`
        }
        return `<h5>Second Template</h5>`
     }

     getTemplate(name: string) : string {
        if (name == "first") {
            return './first.component.html'
        } else {
            return './second.component.html'
        }
     }

     constructor() {}
     ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: CLI is prefixing component selectors with "app-" at generation and they seem to be working fine (besides this issue I am trying to tackle) .

Answer (score 1):

**No** , this cannot be done . You need to refer it statically, otherwise angular will not find the template to load.

Because Angular compiler needs to find the template initially and able to access it. It cant resolve variables or functions.

Look at this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14323

Comment: That is unfortunate. This was possible with angularjs. Thank you for the information.